# How to show hidden layer outputs in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, output, protocol-buffers

I'm having differences of the outputs when comparing a model with its stored protobuf version (via [this conversion script](https://github.com/amir-abdi/keras_to_tensorflow/blob/master/keras_to_tensorflow.py)). For debugging I'm comparing both layers respectively. For the weights and the actual layer output during a test sequence I receive the identical outputs, thus I'm not sure how to access the hidden layers.

Here is how I load the layers

```
    input  = graph.get_tensor_by_name("lstm_1_input_1:0")
    layer1 = graph.get_tensor_by_name("lstm_1_1/kernel:0")
    layer2 = graph.get_tensor_by_name("lstm_1_1/recurrent_kernel:0")
    layer3 = graph.get_tensor_by_name("time_distributed_1_1/kernel:0")
    output = graph.get_tensor_by_name("activation_1_1/div:0")
```

Here is the way what I thought to show the respective elements.

**show weights**:

```
with tf.Session(graph=graph) as sess:
       print sess.run(layer1)
       print sess.run(layer2)
       print sess.run(layer3)
```

**show outputs**:

```
with tf.Session(graph=graph) as sess:
    y_out, l1_out, l2_out, l3_out = sess.run([output, layer1, layer2, layer3], feed_dict={input: X_test})
```

With this code `sess.run(layer1) == sess.run(layer1,feed_dict={input:X_test})` which shouldn't be true.

Can someone help me out?

Comment: But `sess.run(layer1)` is the weights, not the outputs. Why should it change with `input`?

Comment: I'm relatively new to TF, I thought feeding the input layers yields the output at a given level  (e.g. output_node or layer1), where just printing the layer shows the weights (as shown above)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you run `sess.run(layer1)`, you're telling tensorflow to compute the value of `layer1` tensor, which is ...

```
layer1 = graph.get_tensor_by_name("lstm_1_1/kernel:0")
```

... according to your definition. Note that LSTM kernel is the weights variable. It **does not** depend on the `input`, that's why you get the same result with `sess.run(layer1, feed_dict={input:X_test})`. It's not like tensorflow is computing the output if the input is provided -- it's computing the *specified* tensor(s), in this case `layer1`.

When does `input` matter then? When there is a dependency on it. For example:

- `sess.run(output)`. It simply won't work without an `input`, or any tensor that will allow to compute the `input`.
- The optimization op, such as `tf.train.AdapOptimizer(...).minimize(loss)`. Running this op will change `layer1`, but it also needs the `input` to do so.

Comment: thanks for the information, but how do I then access each (hidden) layers output?

Comment: I think the easiest way would be to create a named tensor in the *original* model for LSTM output and find it the same way. See, LSTM output is a [pretty non-trivial formula](http://colah.github.io/posts/2015-08-Understanding-LSTMs/#step-by-step-lstm-walk-through), you don't want to replicate it. Can you show the original model you had?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I only receive the `.pb` file. Which loads perfectly fine but the predictions don't match the expectations by far. I already was looking for some kind of an overview function that lets you, besides the weights, display the network's layout (i.e. out/incoming connections of each node)

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can try TensorBoard and examine your graph to find the outputs of the hidden layers.